# Ajax скроллинг и кнопка назад

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, прокрутка

Всем привет имею такой код, и не знаю как быть:

```js
if (localStorage.getItem("windowscrolltopr") !== null) {
  var windowscrolltop = localStorage.getItem('windowscrolltopr');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: windowscrolltop
  }, 900);
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    console.log(windowscrolltop);
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 600) {
      $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "/getnews.php",
        dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned
        data: {
          lang: lng,
          last_id: $('#news-list div.article-item').last().attr('data-time'),
          ids: $('#news-list div.article-item').last().attr('data-news')
        },
        success: function(response) {
          var content = document.getElementById("news-list");
          content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + response;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }

      });
    }
  });
}



$("#more-news").on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
    type: "GET",
    url: "/getnews.php",
    dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned
    data: {
      lang: lng,
      last_id: $('#news-list div.article-item').last().attr('data-time'),
      ids: $('#news-list div.article-item').last().attr('data-news')
    },
    success: function(response) {
      var content = document.getElementById("news-list");
      content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + response;
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }

  });
  localStorage.setItem('windowscrolltopr', $(window).scrollTop());
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#more-news').offset().top - 90
  }, 900);
});
```

При нажатии на кнопку еще, у меня выгружается контент, когда пользователь кликает на новость и переходит читать ее, то js не понимает, что если он нажмет на кнопку назад, то он захочет вернутся на ту новость, как мне правильно сделать это?